# How should I bind the id attribute using a static prefix in handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I need to bind the id attribute using a prefix something like lz-ID, right now I can get the ID like this:

```
 <img {{bindAttr src="image.thumb_src"}} {{bindAttr id="image.id"}} class='img-polaroid lazy' />
```

I would need something like the class docs, adding a static part:

```
 <img {{bindAttr src="image.thumb_src"}} {{bindAttr id=":lz- image.id"}} class='img-polaroid lazy' />
```

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 2):

You could always create a computed property that had the exact value you wanted.  I'm not aware of a way to specify a prefix otherwise.

In your image object on creation, or after reopening it:

```
htmlId: function(){
  return 'lz-' + this.get('id');
}.property('id')
```

and then

```
<img {{bindAttr src="image.thumb_src"}} {{bindAttr id="image.htmlId"}}
```

Comment: How do you set a static prefix for bound classes?

Comment: I misread your comment. apologies. How are you bind-attr an id? Every time i try to do that, the id doesn't show up at all.

Comment: If ember is assigning an id to it you won't win.  Feel free to ping me on a new question if that doesn't help you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that I won't win. This is a more thorough explanation of my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806067/emberjs-how-to-bind-attr-an-id