# Emberjs how to bind-attr an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to use ember properties to toggle the visibility of a div by calling it's dynamic id, however even though I can do something similar by calling classes, I cannot do the same for id's.

For example: `{{bind-attr class=":class1 controller.controllerProperty:class2"}}` works fine. I can toggle the `controllerProperty` from an action in my controller.

You would think the same concept would apply to id's. However `{{bind-attr id=":staticId  controllerProperty:id{{dynamicIdNumber}}"}}` makes the id's disappear all together!

Why is this happening and what is the correct method to be doing this sort of this? I would like to avoid work-around solutions as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to classes is a special case in Ember as described in [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/)
Binding the other attributes to properties is described [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll let you know how it works.